# Accessing a Public Folder Remotely from WIndows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access, share

I have a client of my who is running Windows 2008 Server. Initially when I setup the client about 3/4 years ago they only had about 4 or so employees so I didn't setup Active Directory. However now they have grown. They have about 15/20 employees in the office and about 15 managers out in the field with laptops. I setup a shared Public folder that all employees can access internally through the LAN. But they want to allow the users out in the field to be able to have access to this folder to.

I read this but didn't really have my situation in mind: [How to access shared folders over Windows Server 2008 VPN from Windows 7 client?](https://serverfault.com/questions/431574/how-to-access-shared-folders-over-windows-server-2008-vpn-from-windows-7-client)

My Equipment:
Dell Server with Windows 2008
Cisco 24 port Switch
Comcast Internet with Router

Could you give my equipment, suggestions and pros/cons about doing it on what I would need to do to successfully and safely give users in the field access to the public folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a VPN as the article you linked suggests.

Comment: but using a VPN will this method work if most of the staff in the field are using air cards? Will that present a problem vs being on a broadband and will they have interruption problems often?